# How to make snow pile in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm trying to make a snow pile appear in my game, which gets bigger when time flows.
[Snow pile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Emhw.jpg)

So, I tried to make it with a custom noise shader.
[My custom shader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO7Cm.png)
[Material made with my shader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1PIU.png)
If I increase the height, the snow pile gets bigger. However, since I used the same material using my custom shader on each snow piles, when I change the height value in one object all the heights of objects change.
Will there be another way to make snow piles or can I make the each of the objects use their own height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two material properties used with MeshRenderer, named material and sharedMaterial. As in

```
GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial;
GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
```

if you modify the material property, it will change the values on that specific object.